# Bing Search -- ACL/Security Filtering

Tags: bing, bing-search, custom-search-provider

Is it possible to filter out search results based on user security/roles using Bing Search API

I know with Google you could use metadata to filter out. Is that the correct way to security filter pages/items from search results for both Google and Bing

Comment: Could you give an example of this? Maybe helpful to answer.

Comment: I as a user have access to page A& B but not C&D. So when I search I see no content from page C&D